# on upgrading magento from 1.3 to 1.7 checkout page is not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.6, magento-1.3

I have upgraded magento 1.3 to 1.7, on checkout page payment information is not displayed.

blank tab is displayed on upgrading it.

do anyone have solution for this.

Comment: Enable log, and share/check it if there is any exception.

Comment: there are no error displayed, actually the content of payment information tab is not displayed.

Comment: can you share URL, so that check browser console if there is JS error?

Comment: http://artifexonline.dyndns.biz:8081/projects/mg_sprcoatings/checkout/onepage/?SID=cvpld5la8mkh5rm8n60knjc821

Comment: If your theme was developed for Magento `1.3`, it's most likely not fully compatible with `1.7`.  Try enabling the default Magento theme and seeing if your issue persists.  If it does, your theme is most likely missing important XML definitions in the layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Themes must be upgraded in order to upgrade Magento. Cart submit button loss on moving from 1.4.2.0 to 1.5.1.0 is a common issue for example.

Also if you're using a third party payment module, it must be upgraded as well. I suspect that your version isn't compatible and either the module itself or its template to display the payment method isn't compatible with 1.7.